# RxJava parallel emit once

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

i try to get an array of flowable get executed in parallel with FlowableFromArray

and emit the FlowableFromArray when all flowables are done.

But I'm missing the method to emit on last/latest.

I could only manage to make it work to emit onNext @see below

```
    val results = FlowableFromArray(flowableArray).parallel()
            .runOn(Schedulers.io())
            .sequential()
            .zipWith(r, BiFunction { t1: Flowable<String>, t2: Int
                ->
                t1
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .map { i -> parseYoutubeTrack(i) }
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe { next -> TLog.i(TAG, "_NEXT_ ${next.videoId}") }

            })
            .subscribe()
```

Comment: This makes no sense; you go parallel to then go back to sequential, then you subscribe in the zip handler. And also what is `r`?

Comment: Made it work like so      return FlowableFromArray(flowableArray)
                .parallel()
                .runOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .map { f -> parseYoutubeTrack(f.blockingFirst()) }
                .sequential()
                .blockingLatest().toMutableList()